# appending a year from a csv files to their corresponding data in a data frame

Tags: r, csv, cbind

I have 12 csv files with names filename_2009.csv, filename_2010.csv, and so on to filename_2021.csv. Each file contains similar data. I have merged all the data into one data frame in R. However I need to add an additional column indicating which year the data is about without modifying the original csv files. How do I do it?
Sorry, I am new to R, so this may be a stupid question.

Comment: When you read the file, before merging all datasets, you could add a new column to that dataset with the year or the filename in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column with the original filename and then extract the year, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
list.files(path="Xxxxxx", full.names=TRUE ) |>
  set_names() |>
  map_dfr(read_csv, .id = "filename") |> 
  mutate(file_year = stringr::str_extract_all(filename, "\\d+"))
```